# Combine multiple array into one array using php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I'm trying to make an array with multiple arrays, the individual arrays are don't have key's the name of the array will be the key of the new array.

For example :

```
$product_name = array('0'=>'product1','2'=>'product2');
$product_id = array('0'=>'1','2'=>'2');
```

I want to display this two arrays into like below

```
$newarray = array(
             "0" => array('product_id'=>1,'product_name'=>'product1'),
             "1" => array('product_id'=>2,'product_name'=>'product2'),

);
```

Comment: Have a look at this array_merge_recursive().

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
$product_name = array('0'=>'product1','2'=>'product2');
$product_id   = array('0'=>'1','2'=>'2');

$new_array = array();
foreach (array_keys($product_id) as $key) {
    $new_array[] = array(
        'product_id'   => $product_id[$key],
        'product_name' => $product_name[$key]
    );
}

print_r($new_array);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [product_name] => product1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [product_name] => product2
        )
)
```

Comment: array_merge_recursive() pretty much does this job